# Check number of options of Drop Down List

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the Drop Down List.

```
Html.DropDownList("MealsSelectedHousesMeals", Model["SelectedMeals"], new { id= "MealsSelectedHousesMeals" })
```

I change dynamically size of it using buttons and javascript actions.
In one of script I check weather this list is empty and then I set content of label.

```
var labelMealType = document.getElementById('labelMealType');
if ($('#MealsSelectedHousesMeals').length >=1)
{
      labelMealType.innerHTML = $('#ListBoxSelectedHousesMeals option:selected').text().split(';')[1];
}
else
{
      labelMealType.innerHTML = 'Selected Meal';
}
```

If this list is empty after a few actions in label shows me caption `undefined` instead `'Selected Meal'`
Definition of label.

```
@Html.Label("Selected Meal",new { id= "labelMealType", style = "border: 1px solid black;font: 12px;" })
```

Do I check in wrong way quantity of options in SelectListItem?

Comment: `id= "MealsSelectedHousesMeals"` probably doesn't work in object type. Use `:` instead of `=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not counting the right thing. Instead of:

```
$('#MealsSelectedHousesMeals').length >=1
```

Do:

```
$('#MealsSelectedHousesMeals>option').length >=1
```